# set up an integral when the following functions revolve around the $x$, $y$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, applications, solid-of-revolution

$y=\sin x$, $y=\frac{1}{2}$, $x=0$
i got the same integral which is
$$
\int_0^{ \frac{5 \pi}{6}} \pi \left(\sin^2(x)- \frac{1}{4}\right) \, \mathrm d x. 
$$
Anyone help
[image]

Comment: The question doesn't make sense and lacks context

Comment: the question is a basic volume of revolution problem.. what is the volume of the revolved graph of the function about the x and y axis also about y=1/2. how about now

Comment: what is the function which you are referring?

Comment: the region bounded by the y=sinx, y=1/2 and x=0. what is the volume. that's what i'm trying to ask

Comment: Start by drawing a picture. Show the rotation axis. Tell us if you are using cylinders or washers as integration method.

Comment: Here you go.. this is what I got for the graph about the x axis.. nd the same thing for the y axis 2 just vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues when you rotate around $x$ axis.

1. The upper limit for integration is $\pi/6$. That's the first value where $\sin x=1/2$.
2. The order of functions in the integral is reversed. The outer radius is $1/2$, the inner radius is $\sin x$.

Therefore $$V_{y=0}=\pi\int_0^{\frac \pi 6}\left(\frac 14-\sin^2 x\right)dx$$

Similarly, if you rotate around axis $y=\frac 12$, you have outer radius $\frac 12-\sin x$ and inner radius $0$. Therefore $$V_{y=\frac 12}=\pi\int_0^{\frac\pi6}\left(\frac 12-\sin x\right)^2dx$$

When you rotate around the $y$ axis ($x=0$), the inner radius is $0$, the outer radius is the value of $x$ where $\sin x=y$, so $x=\arcsin y$. Then $$V_{x=0}=\pi\int_0^{\frac 12}\arcsin^2 y dy$$